# Losing Attribute Hashmap in Session

Tags: java, session, hashmap

I'm facing a trouble when try to get the hashmap from session. Below are my code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String passWord = request.getParameter("passWord");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    User user = new User(userName, passWord);
    if(LoginUtils.DoInsert(user) == null) {
        Map<String, User> listUser = (HashMap<String, User>) session.getAttribute("listUser");
        User Sessionuser = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
    else {
        session.setAttribute("listUser", LoginUtils.getListUser());
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
}
```

The first time, I persist Attribute listUser to session (else block) but the second time, when I tried to retrieve listUser, it get null here (if block). As the debugging, I can see, user Object is still inside the session but the listUser is not. This issue only happens when I use Eclipse, Netbeans works fine. I have tested on both IDE with the same code.
I'm not sure is something wrong with my code or Eclipse
Please give me some advices. Thanks so much

Comment: Make sure to check that `LoginUtils.getListUser()` didn't return null in the line `session.setAttribute("listUser", LoginUtils.getListUser());`

Comment: I have checked and can make sure that it's not null